# windows 7 64 bit : Nvidia optimus "hardware not found" error when installing driver

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Samsung NP550P5C-S03IN laptop. It came with a windows 8.

Did a format and I installed windows 7 on my machine, installed drivers and right now I have a ready system with everything but I am not able to install the drivers for NVIDIA graphic card.

When I try to install the divers following error comes up :
[image]

I can not find the NVIDIA display hardware in device manager also

[image]

I am out of options on how to now have my machine detect the hardware and install the drivers.
I tried to google but can not find much info

Help guys ??

Comment: You must use the drivers directly from Samsung: http://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/NP550P5C-S03IN-downloads. the generic nVIDIA driver often fail to install correctly

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am using the drivers from samsung website

Answer (score 1):

After trying various solutions searched for online. The following thing worked for me.

I restored the default settings in BIOS and then installed the driver

To restore default settings in BIOS

1. Restart your System
2. As it restarts, press F2 key. The system will enter BIOS settings
3. Here locate and select "Restore system defaults"
4. Locate Save and Resent and select Yes
5. The system will restart.